# AsyncBridge.portable for Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, async-await, portable-class-library

I created application with mvvmcross and I want to target WPF, andoid and ios.

I used task and async/await in my core PCL library.
It works with WPF and Android because I use Microsoft.Bcl.Async and AsyncBridge.Portable from Daniel Plaisted.

My problem is with ios version because Daniel not implemented AsyncBridge.Portable for ios.

I would like to know if someone maked it or if someone know where I can find source code of AsyncBridge.Portable of Daniel ?

If Daniel, you sees this post, can you explained me how can I make ios version ? :)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can find the source code [here](http://sdrv.ms/Ux31lr).  From that, you may be able to just adapt the Android code to work on iOS.

However, official Xamarin PCL support is coming soon (-ish), and that may change how you need to do this (or make it so you don't need to do it at all).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope that Xamarin will add support soon